# Incorrect field type on table creation within Talend

Tags: amazon-redshift, talend

We are making use of tRedshiftOutputBulk exec and we have set it to 'Drop table if exists and create' as an action on table. The problem is that a Date field of with a pattern of 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ' is being created as Timestamp rather than TimestampTZ on Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

@mark

What pattern have you given in Date format and Time format field of the component?

Comment: I am using 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ' as per Talend's suggestion

Comment: try  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'TZ'"

Answer (score 0):

you can use the change time pattern 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssTZ'

Comment: unfortunately TZ is not an legal pattern, Talend throws the following exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'